# MAUI Equivalent for Dispatcher.Run

Tags: maui, dispatcher

In WPF applications, I could create a new thread, get the Systems.Windows.Dispatcher for that thread, and call Dispatcher.Run to get dispatcher services for the new thread.  If I call Dispatcher.GetForCurrentThread() on a newly-created thread in MAUI, it just returns a null.  Is there a similar capability in MAUI for dispatcher-like operations on a newly-created thread?

Comment: What do you need that for? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Code sharing with our WPF version of the application.  We have some in-house video controls that make their own thread with their own dispatcher in WPF, and we use it for testing localization.

Answer (score 0):

For MAUI, there are several ways to use:

- `BindableObject.Dispatcher.Dispatch()`
- `Dispatcher.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatch()`
- `MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread()`

About their specific differences, You can refer to [mattleibow's answer](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions/7518#discussioncomment-2857071) on GitHub, and he said:

> There is also a `Dispatcher.GetForCurrentThread()` that can be used. This is different to MainThread in that MainThread will always try find a UI thread. `GetForCurrentThread` will return null if the current thread has no dispatcher.

In addition, you can also see this answer of ToolmakerSteve on so: [For Dotnet Maui, what the difference between Application.Current?.Dispatcher.Dispatch(async()) and MainThread.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74805342/19902734).

Wish these can help you :-)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'd looked at those.  The issue is that those all deal with a window's main dispatcher (the UI thread).  I want to start my own thread with a dispatcher that is a background thread.  This can be done in WPF/Windows, but I haven't found built-in support for it in MAUI yet.  I'm currently writing my own background-thread dispatcher for MAUI.

Comment: You mean background thread? [.net MAUI c# Background Task ContinueWith and notification Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73403608/net-maui-c-sharp-background-task-continuewith-and-notification-event) could give a hint to you.